# Derivative of fraction

Tags: calculus

How to find the deravitive of $\frac{x}{1+y}$ with respect to $y$? If it is with respect to $x$ it is no problem, but this is the harder case. Thanks

Comment: Chain rule gives you the clue.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the quotient rule:
$$\dfrac{d}{dy}\left(\dfrac{f(y)}{g(y)}\right)=\dfrac{g(y)\times f^\prime(y)-f(y)\times g^\prime(y)}{(g(y))^2}$$
Let $x=f(y),g(y)=1+y$.